# I'd like to send an email to users who subscribe to my webpage by clicking a button

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

pretty new here so I apologize if this question has been asked before. I have been asked to create a website that shows a series of tickets that the company's employees open regarding a problem. Problem is whenever someone opens a ticket, or updates the status of it, or comments on it, or however else a change occurs in the ticket, the creator of the ticket gets an email and whoever the ticket is assigned to gets an email too.

My job is to create a website that the employees can go and look at all the tickets and when an admin makes a change in the ticket, he/she will choose to send notifications to users who are subscribed to the website.

I am using React app, express, nodejs, and all those good stuff to accomplish this task. I recently found out about Nodemailer and I used it in my program and it works great, but every time I run my program it sends an email. I want this to happen whenever I click on "Notification" button AND whenever a ticket selected. Here is my code for the button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import axios from "axios";

class Submit extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log("Notification sent!");
  }
 render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.handleClick} color="danger" style={{ position: 
"absolute", bottom: "1px" }}>
        Send Notification
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

export default Submit;
```

and here is where my email is being sent from:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
         user: 'email@gmail.com',
         pass: 'password'
     }
 });

let mailOptions = {
  from: '"FirstLastname" email@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: 'email@yahoo.com', // list of receivers
      subject: 'hey there', // Subject line
      text: 'Email notification sending', // plain text body
      html: '<b>Notification!</b>' // html body
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You need to send an HTTP request from handleClick() to email sender route.

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani Could you go into detail on how I can achieve that? I'm fairly new to this and it was just dumped on me to figure things out. Are there tutorials you'd recommend reading or watching to get a better idea of how to do what i'm trying to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you call `transporter.sendMail` on the initialisation of the class...

You need to wrap it inside a function and call it for example inside the `handleClick` function of the Submit component.

I would approach this by a “helper” class like this (**Attention: untested code example!**)

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

class NodemailerHelper {

    constructor() {

        this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'email@gmail.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });

    }

    sendMail(from, to, subject, html) {

        this.mailOptions = {
            from: from,
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            html: html
        };

        this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {

            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
            console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))

            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }else {
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

}

const nodemailerHelper = new NodemailerHelper();

export default nodemailerHelper;
```

So now you need to import the `nodemailerHelper` to your `Submit` component and just call `nodemailerHelper.sendMail(from, to, subject, html)` from your `handleClick` function